# Is Telerik Extensions for ASP. NET MVC Free?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

Reading on the Telerik [blog](http://blogs.telerik.com/atanaskorchev/posts/09-08-12/announcing_a_new_product_line_-_telerik_extensions_for_asp_net_mvc.aspx), the ASP.NET MVC Suite is GPL license. Does that mean it is free of charge? That would be great because it is a very nice looking suite of controls, but $999 is non-trivial.

I am building an internal application which will provide an admin interface to a SqlServer database. (Won't be exposed to public Internet). So I am not really selling the application, having a GPL license should not be a problem.

Comment: that link says it's MSPL licensed, not GPL.

Comment: The blog page is several years old. The current FAQ page states it GPL V2. http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The blog post is a little old but on Telerik's site they have some good info on this.

What's free / open source is what is available on the [CodePlex site](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/).  As mentioned on the CodePlex page, it's a framework that might be helpful to you...

> Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC is
>   a lightweight framework which helps
>   you build rich user interfaces for
>   ASP.NET MVC while enjoying great
>   developer productivity.

Telerik has additional information posted on this to clear up the question.

http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx
From their license FAQ Page:

> How do you license Telerik Extensions
>   for ASP.NET MVC product?  We offer two
>   licensing options for Telerik
>   Extensions for ASP.NET MVC.
>
> Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC
>   Open Source GPL (Open Source License)
>   This is a suitable option if you are
>   building an application for internal
>   use or an open source application with
>   a license compatible with the GNU GPL
>   v2.0.
>
> Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC
>   Commercial License (Developer License
>   with Subscription and Priority
>   Support) This is a suitable option if
>   you are building closed-source
>   commercial products for redistribution
>   or if you wish to avoid integrating
>   open-source components into your
>   application.  This license is provided
>   per developer, so you need to purchase
>   the appropriate number of developer
>   seats from Telerik.

Since you are developing an internal app then you appear to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's the [Microsoft Public License](http://www.microsoft.com/opensource/licenses.mspx#Ms-PL) (Ms-PL) not the LGPL/GPL which have very specific requirements around opening of your source.

From my reading of the above licence it doesn't require you to redistribute your source but IANAL etc.

Comment: The blog page is several years old. The current FAQ page states it GPL V2. http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx. It's also listed this way on the CodePlex License page.